# SharedPreferences doesn't save value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have this code:

```
public class Register extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout layout;
    private TextView debug;
    public static final String USER_CONFIG = "UserConfigs";

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(USER_CONFIG, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean registered = settings.getBoolean("registered", false);

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutRegister);

        if (!registered) {
            debug = new TextView(this);
            debug.setText("You have to register");
            layout.addView (debug);

            //TO DO user registration

            settings.edit().putBoolean("registered", true);
            settings.edit().commit(); 
        } else {
            debug = new TextView(this);
            debug.setText("You have already registered");
            layout.addView (debug);
            //TO DO skip to next screen
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm always getting registered as "false" when I restart my app. I have tried to commit it on the `onStop()` as well and got the same result. I have seen other topics with this problem here but none of them had the same problem as I do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
settings.edit().putBoolean("registered", true);
settings.edit().commit();
```

You need to get the editor object, then make the changes:

```
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean(...);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is SharedPreferences.Editor. It worked. But can you explain me why? Maybe because when I just call the methods he may call on different "objects"?

Comment: Yes, each time you call `.edit()` it resets the Editor object, hence when you call it for `.commit()`, it wipes out the boolean you put into it.

Comment: You can, however, do `settings.edit().putBoolean("registered", true).commit();` (as far as I can remember)

Comment: Why not use `apply()` instead of `commit()`?

Comment: this is not working on Galaxy S3 but other phones it work well

Answer (score 2):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager  
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);  
                Editor edit = prefs.edit();  
                edit.putBoolean("registered", true);
                edit.commit();
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are also correct.

You can also use this

`settings.edit().putBoolean("registered", true).commit();`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. See the answer of cjk, he explains pretty well why !